# Uninitialized constant many_to_many association in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 model with the association many_to_many. When creating a brand I have error:

> NameError in Admin::Brands#new
>   Showing /.../app/views/admin/brands/_form.html.slim where line #3 raised:
>   uninitialized constant Brand::BrandCatalog

What am I doing wrong?

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_catalogs
  has_many :brands, through: :brand_catalogs
end

#app/models/brand.rb
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_catalogs
  has_many :categories, through: :brand_catalogs
end

#app/models/brandcatalog.rb
class BrandCatalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :brand
end
```

migration

```
#db/migrate/20151230092013_create_brand_catalogs.rb
class CreateBrandCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :brand_catalogs, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :brand_id
    end

    add_index :brand_catalogs, [:category_id, :brand_id]
  end
end
```

brands controller

```
#app/controllers/admin/brands_controller.rb
class Admin::BrandsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :require_login
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :load_brand, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @brands = Brand.all
  end

  def new
    @brand = Brand.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @brand = Brand.create(brand_params)
    if @brand.save
     redirect_to admin_brands_path, notice: 'Brand was successfully created.'
    else
     render :new, notice: 'Something wrong!'
   end

  def update

  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def load_brand
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
    end

    def brand_params
      params.require(:brand).permit(:title, {category_ids: []})
    end
end
```

brands form

```
# views/admin/brands/_form.html.slim
= bootstrap_form_for [:admin, @brand] do |f|
  div class='form-group'
    = f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :title)

  div class='form-group'
    = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Comment: If you have set id: false for brand_catalogs table then what is use of :through relationship?

Comment: Use `has_and_belongs_to_many` or add `id` to your `CreateBrandCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I delete `through: :brand_catalogs` from brand.rb and it solved the problem. but now when saving brand i have new error:
`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Admin::BrandsController#create
can't write unknown attribute "brand_id"`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk, I have brand_id and category_id in CreateBrandCatalogs < ActiveRecord::Migration. id for brand_catalog create automatically. 
or I do not understand what id do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your `#app/models/brandcatalog.rb` file to `brand_catalog.rb`. Modelnames needs to have matching filenames but with underscore instead of camelcase.

For example a model called `ThisIsMyModel` should have its file named `this_is_my_model.rb`

Comment: Exactly! How could I miss it).
Now the controller does not save the brand. But that is another story

Comment: Thats because you don't save it, you just initialize it with `new`. Try adding `@brand.save` or `@brand = Brand.create(brand_params)`. You should probably add some if statement when saving as well in case some of the params are faulty.

Comment: I corrected the controller in question. but without results.

Comment: Now you're trying to first create the object and then save it. You should first initialize it with `@brand = Brand.new(brand_params)` and then run `if @brand.save`. If it's not stored there could be some errors when saving. If you run `save!` instead of `save` the application will halt on errors and you should be able to see it in the console.

Comment: Ok. I now I can see error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in Admin::BrandsController#create Validation failed: Brand catalogs is invalid, Brand catalogs is invalid`

Comment: the problem was the validation in model BrandCatalog. fix it. thanks again for your help.